# Is there a .NET library that can do string permutations or string expansion?

Tags: c#, .net, permutation

What I'm looking for is some library or some code of classes that can be used to expand construction strings into variations and permutations. Something like the following (syntax is mine, may be different):

```
construction string: [Ff]oo [Bbß]ar|F(oo|oe)
output strings:
  Foo Bar
  foo Bar
  Foo bar
  foo bar
  Foo ßar
  foo ßar
  Foo
  Foe
```

While it wouldn't be too hard to build this myself, if it's around, why bother reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't follows your syntax, but I use it in some projects and runs very smooth: [Permutations, Combinations, and Variations using C# Generics](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx)

Comment: Looks like doing what I need. Let me try it out.