# string permutations with multiple string words

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I would like to generate permutations of string words that are inputted from a file. I know the count and was wondering if there is an easy way to do this using an arraylist.

Comment: You mean, given a string consisting of several words, you want to print all the permutations of words that compose that string?  If so, that's an easy and fun recursive (or iterative if you like pain) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Great article on MSDN Magazine: [String Permutations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163513.aspx)

[Combination Generator in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774457/combination-generator-in-linq) (this one has a LINQ based answer)

Using the code provided in the above link:

```
string str = "leniel";

var permutations = GetPermutations(str);

foreach (string s in permutations)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

Console.WriteLine(permutations.Count()); // 720 permutations

Console.ReadLine();
```

More links to help:

[Listing all permutations of a string/integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756055/listing-all-permutations-of-a-string-integer)

[Permutations with LINQ](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/linqprojectgeneral/thread/55157f09-ffd3-4fa0-a668-c3a8d5bfb809)

[Generating (word) combinations (permutations) out of a string](http://blogs.vbcity.com/hotdog/archive/2005/03/12/1176.aspx)

[Is there a .NET library that can do string permutations or string expansion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065824/is-there-a-net-library-that-can-do-string-permutations-or-string-expansion)

[Are there any better methods to do permutation of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995328/are-there-any-better-methods-to-do-permutation-of-string)

[Generate list of all possible permutations of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361/generate-list-of-all-possible-permutations-of-a-string)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just realized I had it wrong and what I need to do is combinations of the strings with the order not changing but selection does. Also it should be n(n-1)/2 results.

Answer (score 0):

Since this doesn't have a `homework` tag, I'd suggest using a `std::vector` of words and `std::next_permutation`. (If it *had* a `homework` tag, I'd suggest how to implement something like `std::next_permutation`.)

Comment: Sometimes all these libraries take the fun out of programming ;)

Comment: Its not homework...I have a bunch of nouns I compiled by using SharpNLP and now wish to produce permutations of length 5 using each noun. I realize its a recursive method required but not sure how to implement it since all searches on this does not produce a clear method. But I will keep checking thanks..